# Symfony2 with IvoryCKEditor and FMElfinder wrong url when select the picture

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, elfinder

I already configured Symfony2 with IvoryCKEditor and FMElfinder. I can upload and see all the files correctly. But when I select the file in the dialog window it seems like the url referenced by the selected file is wrong. I only see a red icon of error in the preview. May be some configuration is missing?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in its issues page. https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle/issues/99. Just needed the configuration option relative_path: false